# How to force youtube site auto-generated to create closed caption for an uploaded video on its site

Tags: self-learning, listening

I have an idea for intermediate language learners who want to improve their languages skills by using video on youtube. Learners could improve listening skill by watching videos in target language. If the videos are provided with subtitles or associated with closed caption (auto-generated), then it is amazing. The learners in intermediate level could check out the transcript or closed caption after listening some times. However, it is impossible to get feedback whether learners could understand videos
well or not when there is neither subtitle nor closed caption.

My question is how to force youtube to create a closed caption (auto-generated) when one uploads a video on their own youtube channel.

PS: I got an answer. There is an app for android phone, called Live Transcribe. This app could transcribe the audio or video when one opens the app and video/audio at the same time.

Comment: Hi. While captions can be useful to language learners (provided that they are accurate enough), I don't think that asking how you can force YouTube to create captions is on topic here. (It is a purely technical question rather than a learning question.) With regard to the substance of your question: [YouTube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6373554?hl=en) says the uploader determines whether captions should be automatically generated or not, and lists the languages that are supported.

Comment: Hi @Tsundoku Thanks for our reply. I was trying to find a right place to ask this question. I googled it but I haven't got an answer. This question is sort of between learning language tool and editor video technique with youtute. I had tried the instruction in Youtube Help. But many times videos in interesting topics (for me in my target-language) are not generating its closed caption despite my attempts . 
PS: if you know right place to ask this question, please let me know.